# undifined error when displaying values of php json encoded array by jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to display data that received from jquery post. but it is giving me an error saying undefined

my php json encoded array is this.

```
[{"matId":"7","matName":"test","matBrand":"est","matPackaging":"1","matWidth":"434","matHeight":"23","matLength":"23","matWeight":"23","matArea":"23","matVolume":"23","matPerPack":"32","supplier1":"19","supplier2":"19","supplier3":"19","requiredInPhase":"","stockItem":"1"}]
```

then in jquery I am trying to alert one of this value, but it gives error 'undefined'.

this is my jquery code

```
$('#matId').on('change', function() {
            var matId = $(this).val();
            $.post('<?php echo base_url() . 'display_mat_details'; ?>', {matId: matId}, function(redata) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(redata);
                alert(obj.matId);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is enclosed within the `[]` that's an array.So u need to use `[0]` to get first object from the array

```
$('#matId').on('change', function() {
  var matId = $(this).val();
  $.post('<?php echo base_url() . '
    display_mat_details '; ?>', {
      matId: matId
    }, function(redata) {
      var obj = $.parseJSON(redata);
      alert(obj[0].matId);
    });
});
```

**Example:**

```js
var str = [{"matId":"7","matName":"test","matBrand":"est","matPackaging":"1","matWidth":"434","matHeight":"23","matLength":"23","matWeight":"23","matArea":"23","matVolume":"23","matPerPack":"32","supplier1":"19","supplier2":"19","supplier3":"19","requiredInPhase":"","stockItem":"1"}];
alert(str[0].matId);
```

Comment: This does work, however doesn't look overly cool. If the OP has access to change the returned data then that would be the first choice rather than subscripting the result.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because your JSON is an array containing an object... Remove the square brackets around the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code
replace `obj.matId` with `obj[0].matId`

```
  $('#matId').on('change', function() {
                var matId = $(this).val();
                $.post('<?php echo base_url() . 'display_mat_details'; ?>', {matId: matId}, function(redata) {
                   // var obj = $.parseJSON(redata);// error here structure of redata is wrong
                   // alert(obj[0].matId);
                    alert(redata[0].matId);
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

and to use

```
$.parseJSON()
```

your array structure should be like this

```
var Content = '{"matId":"7","matName":"test","matBrand":"est","matPackaging":"1","matWidth":"434","matHeight":"23","matLength":"23","matWeight":"23","matArea":"23","matVolume":"23","matPerPack":"32","supplier1":"19","supplier2":"19","supplier3":"19","requiredInPhase":"","stockItem":"1"}';

var obj = $.parseJSON(Content);
alert(obj.matId);
```